# Any way to get the type of Tuple<> item(s)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

where the def is

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, double>> GetValues()
{
   ....
       yield return new Tuple<string,double>(dataRow["<field>"].ToString(),
               (double)Convert.ChangeType(dataRow["<field>"], typeof(double)));
   ....

   // and more code similar to above based on other custom logic

}
```

as you can see, that,s a lot of casting/coerc'ng to double
it may still change back to string or to other datatypes

wondering if there is a way to get the datatypes of Tuple defined in the signature so i can create some generic helper and not worry about missing some conversion somewhere

It should be possible with Reflection? i hope !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx?ppud=4) class, you have a nice extension method called [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) for this.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> GetValues<T1, T2>(String field1, String field2)
{
   ....
       yield return new Tuple<T1,T2>(dataRow.Field<T1>("<field>"),
               dataRow.Field<T2>("<field>"));
   ....
}
```

Comment: Pass a `Nullable<T>` instead of a T, for instance `GetValues<double?, int?>(...)`

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of the Tuple you can get the generic type parameters via reflection:

```
var x = Tuple.Create<int, string>(0, "test");
var y = x.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
y[0].Name = "System.Int32";
```

You can get this same information at compile-time using "typeof()", or at runtime using reflection, like so:

```
public Tuple<string, double> DoSomething()
{
  var y = typeof(Tuple<string, double>).GetGenericArguments();
  var z = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReturnType.GetGenericArguments();
}
```

I don't think this is really going to help you; you can't bind the type information obtained at run-time to generic parameters at compile type, so you aren't saving yourself a whole lot of work. You will still end up having to specify the data types repeatedly somewhere.

Chris Shain's answer (the `Field<T>` method) really is the way to go here.

Comment: any way to get the tuple instance off the method signature as above ?

Comment: sorry i meant if there is something along the lines of var y = GetTheReturnTypeOfThisMethod();

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could the following be of help?

```
bool bStringResult = false, bDoubleResult = false;
string sString = string.Empty;
double dDouble = 0;

Tuple<string, double> tTuple = Tuple.Create(sString, dDouble);

if (tTuple.Item1.GetType() == typeof(string)) bStringResult = true;
if (tTuple.Item2.GetType() == typeof(double)) bDoubleResult = true;

Console.WriteLine($"String: {bStringResult}, Double: {bDoubleResult}");
```

Result : String: True, Double: True